# No detail in Swagger docs for Spring Data Rest's GET requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I'm testing out Swagger-UI with a rest api generated by Spring Data Rest.

I have a very basic repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
}
```

but in Swagger-UI docs for getting an employee, I get pretty useless info:

[image]

In other places such as posting an employee, I can see the actual Entity details:

[image]

Anyone have any idea how I can get the Entity details to show up for the GET method as well?